# How to use query from firestore using timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a date range picker where I will let my user set the date range of the data that they will query from firestore. I already can get the value of the date range picker and store it from a variable. My problem is I don't know how to query on firestore referencing timestamps.

this is my function for querying documents from a firestore collection. So far I can only collect all data but can't collect filtered data (by timestamps).

```
export async function Getfs(){
console.log("Get firestore run >>");
var f = document.getElementById("firstDate").value; // starting date
var s = document.getElementById("secondDate").value; // ending date
const fs_snap = await getDocs(query(collection(fs, "sens02"),orderBy('ts')));
}
```

[This is what my firestore document looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OLt.png)

and this is how I designed my date range picker using html input date
[date range picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrA1E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the methods of the [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp) class.

More precisely, in your case, you need to use the `fromDate()` as shown in the below example:

```
const q = query(
  collection(fs, "sens02"),
  where('ts', '>=', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('2022-05-28'))) // For example we use the 28/05/2002
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data().ts.toDate());
});
```

Comment: Wow, it does the magic! Thank you. What if aside from starting date I want to include the ending date. Should I just add another `where ('ts', '<=', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date({endingdate}));` after the first where function?

Comment: Yes you need to add this where clause. You'll have to create an index: the first time you execute the query an error message will be shown which contains an URL that will help you.

Comment: I notice a problem. I have documents that have timestamps of either 2022-05-22 and 2022-05-24. This is my code
`fs_snap = await getDocs(query(collection(fs, "sens02"),orderBy('ts'), where('ts', '>=', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(startingDate))),where('ts', '<=', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date({endingDate})))));` if I set my starting date to 2022-05-22 it gets all the data from May 22 however if I set my endingDate to 2022-05-24 I can't query the documents that have timestamps of May 24, 2022. Is there a way I can query documents from May 24 but still having 2022-05-24 as my endingDate?

Comment: You should probably add the time of midnight in the ending date. I suspect the timestamp is calaulated for 00:00 on a given date. Or do `where('ts', '<', Timestamp.fromDate(new Date({endingDate})))))`with 2022-05-26. See the `<`instead of `<=`

Comment: If I should add the time of midnight to the endingDate, what would my endingDate should look like? I tried changing the `<` to `<=` on the second where clause but still didn't filter date from May 24.

Comment: You need to debug. First try the two clauses independently then add them.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to debug just the way you suggested, and I found out that the endingDate only covers the 00:00:00 time of the May 24th and doesn't read the documents past 00:00:00 so I have to specify the time on my endingDate. so my endingDate looks like this `2022-05-24T15:59:59Z` noticed that instead of `23:59:59` I used `15:59:59` because the code automatically adds my GMT which is plus 8 hours.